# Monitoring CPU usage using MS tools

Tags: windows, performance, cpu, monitoring, event-viewer

Can CPU usage be monitored in Event Viewer? I don't want to use a third-party software. Can I set a rule so that Event Viewer can show me if the CPU usage gets higher than a set value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Event Viewer*? No, that only shows events. You can however use the *Performance* MMC snap-in. Run `perfmon.msc` then you can view the CPU usage as well as a bevy of other performance counters.

You can also configure it to log an event to the Application system log by adding and configuring an alert.

**Figure 1:** Adding a performance alert in XP (a little less direct, but similar in 7)

[image]

Comment: Task manger as well...

Comment: Yes, but Task Manager does not let you set thresholds or log events.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can explore the possibilities of the command line eventcreate.exe in system32...

**2)** Follow the advice of Synetech

Here's a short How To from MSDN Blog: How To: Use Perfmon in Windows 7

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/securitytools/how-to-use-perfmon-in-windows-7)

The files for your Performances collector for the CPU will be save in *C:\PerfLogs*

**But** this is not a complete answer to your question since, *as far as I know*, the perfmon use built-in performances counters and not a user created counters such as a *«CPU usage gets higher than a set value»* (*This must be verified!*)